# Grounding an Inverter, good or bad if also plugged into a grounded AC Outlet?

Tags: grounding

If you have an DC/AC Inverter with a AC Transfer switch (so it also connects to grid power AC/110V to pull power from the grid when/if the 12V battery source drains down), and the inverter instructions say to ground the metal body, with provided grounding screw, is it a good or bad idea to ground the Inverter body to a ground rod if the Inverter will simultaneously be plugged into a GFCI A/C Receptacle?

Comment: Hi, this is more of a diy.stackexchange.com question. Grounding and Neutral connection of inverters is a complex topic, see for example the [manual of this Victron inverter](https://www.victronenergy.com/upload/documents/Manual-MultiPlus-Compact-800-1200-1600-EN-NL-FR-DE-ES.pdf) for some clues.

Comment: @tomnexus Or maybe electronics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @MikeWaters. No. The EE stack will just kick this to DIY.